# What means Command column in sp_who2 and text column in sys.dm_exec_sql_text?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ddl, dmv, scripting

I have a script that shows commands being fired in SQL Server 2008 database as follows:

```
--shows who is active and executed commands
declare @SPID int=null,
    @Status varchar(max) = null,
    @LOGIN varchar(max) = null,
    @HostName varchar(max) = null,
    @DBName varchar(max) = NULL,
    @Command varchar(max) = null

declare @sql varchar(max)=''

set @sql='use master;DECLARE @Table TABLE(SPID INT,Status VARCHAR(MAX),LOGIN VARCHAR(MAX),HostName VARCHAR(MAX),BlkBy VARCHAR(MAX),DBName VARCHAR(MAX),Command VARCHAR(MAX),CPUTime INT,DiskIO INT,LastBatch VARCHAR(MAX),ProgramName VARCHAR(MAX),SPID_1 INT,REQUESTID INT);INSERT INTO @Table EXEC sp_who2;

SELECT  w.SPID,w.Status,w.LOGIN,w.HostName,w.BlkBy,w.DBName,w.Command,r.estimated_completion_time/60000.0 as remaining_minutes, r.percent_complete,r.total_elapsed_time/60000.0 as minutes,r.reads,r.writes,t.text,w.CPUTime,w.DiskIO,w.LastBatch,w.ProgramName,w.SPID_1,w.REQUESTID    FROM @Table w 
inner join sys.dm_exec_requests AS r on w.SPID=r.session_id 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS t WHERE 1=1'
    if @SPID is not null
        set @sql=@sql+' and SPID='+@SPID
    if @Status is not null
        set @sql=@sql+' and upper(Status) like ''%'+upper(@Status)+'%'''
    if @LOGIN is not null
        set @sql=@sql+' and upper(LOGIN) like ''%'+upper(@LOGIN)+'%'''
    if @HostName is not null
        set @sql=@sql+' and upper(HostName) like ''%'+upper(@HostName)+'%'''
    if @DBName is not null
        set @sql=@sql+' and upper(DBName) like ''%'+upper(@DBName)+'%'''
    if @Command is not null
        set @sql=@sql+' and upper(Command) like ''%'+upper(@Command)+'%'''

exec (@sql)
```

I have noticed that there are DDL commands for **creating a procedure**, but I am not sure if *the procedure is really being created* or if *this is just an information to tell which procedure was called*.

[image]

Does anyone know what *UPDATE* really means in `Command` column? 
And the `text` column from `sys.dm_exec_sql_text`: is ist a called procedure or a procedure being altered/created?

Answer (score 1):

The `text` value shows the procedure in which the statement that is being executed resides. The `Command` references the action of the executing statement within the procedure

To find the exact statement within the procedure that is being called, you'll need to use the `statement_start_offset` and `statement_end_offset` from `dm_exec_requests`.

Add the following to the list of columns selected:

```
,SUBSTRING(text, (statement_start_offset/2)+1,
                            ((CASE statement_end_offset WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(text)
                                  ELSE statement_end_offset
                                END - statement_start_offset)/2)+1)
```